# Why Simulink 2012b is slow compared to old versions (< 2010bSP2)

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have migrated from Simulink 2010bSP2 to 2012b and I noticed a very poor performance slowdown. What I mean is: working with the model, zooming in, copying, paste, adding new blocks, compiling, running is slower.

The same model, with same settigns run faster in 2010bSP2

What happened ? Do the new versions of Matlab (2014 ->) have fixed this problem?

Comment: Do you notice a slow-down in simulation or compilation? Or is it only UI actions?

Comment: All actions : Simulation, compilation AND UI actions.   The most severe degradation is for compilation

Comment: The new UI shouldn't have an impact on compilation...
If you can, I'd definitely try working with a newer release. It's also much more stable in my experience.

Comment: But performance wise I never had such a bad experience like you described

Comment: @pmb, the lag is, of course, amplified by veryyy big models ( my case )

Comment: Haha trust me I've also seen some biggies ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab R2012a introduced quite a few new features since R2011b, especially the new UI, the new "Simulink Editor". It seems like your problems are mostly related with the UI, so this could be the explanation.

I would definitely try a newer version and check that your hardware has enough RAM. Otherwise try contacting Mathworks support.

Comment: I am running in a 16gb ram pc, so it has enough power. Do you think I should configure something in simulink, for example, Java heap space or anything else.

Comment: @guilhermecgs I have a 16Gb RAM computer and MATLAB goes smoooooothly. Maybe processor is old? Anyway, contact MAthworks

Comment: I am noticing this too. R2020 runs very slow compared to an old version, e.g. R2011 for simple models. Is this normal?